# Is there any possibility of interspecies sexual reproduction in animals like hybridizing plants?

Tags: human-biology, zoology

Inter-species sexuals are happening naturally. My questions is, whether it may lead a creation of new species? This question arises, because of the appearance of **Pillayar** in hinduism. Please clarify, whether it is possible to create a new species with the appearance of "Vinayagar" that is human body with elephant face.

Comment: You might explain what Pillayar and Vinayagar are, for the benefit of those who aren't that familiar with Hindu culture.  But closely-related species can produce offspring: mules, wolf-dog,coyote-dog, and coyote-wolf hybrids, ligers and tigons, "beefalo" (cow-buffalo), and more.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is : A big NO.

Naturally, there is no way possible to create a species like vinayagar. Humans and elephants are totally different, they belong to totally different orders. And success rate of inter-species reproduction is rare for even species from same family but from different genus.